# android crop/save image after zoom and drag

Tags: android, image, image-processing, frame, drag

in my application I want to have a frame (with a hole in the middle) and an image under it.  I want to be able to drag and zoom the image to fit (the face in the picture) it in the frame. Then Crop the image (could I find the pixel x,y that are in the border of the screen?)   and then save the zoomed image so that I can put the frame over it then.

Any suggestions?  If possible please tell me the classes I will have to use.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do all the functionalities (What you have discussed above) using Android View class with onDraw method and canvas Object.
Refer the link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html